# Gridview: Detail page having different screens

Tags: android, gridview

In Gridview when am selecting each item its going to same same page. but i need to go different pages according to icon name

Here is my java class

```
rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
                //Add the position to the intent to be used in the second activity.
                intent.putExtra("position", position);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

what changes i should make ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *onClickListener*,you have to try *onItemClickListener*.
where you find position of listview item.
**Code:-**

```
rowView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
                //Add the position to the intent to be used in the second activity.
                intent.putExtra("position", position);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

I hope its help you.

Comment: Error:(73, 16) error: cannot find symbol method setOnItemClickListener(<anonymous OnItemClickListener>)

Comment: rowView consider as your listview!